# How to create an x=y-axis

Tags: maple

I have this wave in Maple, but I don't want to have the whole square showing, I just want one of the triangular parts visible. Hope that makes sense. Basically I need to axis to go from say `x=0..1`, `y=0..1` and `x=y`. It is this `x=y` axis which I can't get.

This is the code which I have so far.

```
with(plots):
animate(plot3d,[sin(Pi*2*x)*sin(Pi*y)*sin(t)-sin(Pi*x)*sin(Pi*2*y)*sin(t),x=0..1, y=0..1],t=0..2*Pi);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plot3d` command offers a syntax where either (or both) of the endpoints in the `range` supplied for one of the plotting variables can be an expression in terms of the other plotting variable.

So instead of `x=0..1, y=0..1` to denote a rectangular domain you could use `x=0..y, y=0..1` to denote a triangular domain. The remaining triangular domain could be denoted using `x=y..1, y=0..1`.

You utilized this functionality in another of your recent questions.

```
with(plots):

animate(plot3d,[sin(Pi*2*x)*sin(Pi*y)*sin(t)
                -sin(Pi*x)*sin(Pi*2*y)*sin(t),
                x=0..y, y=0..1],
        t=0..2*Pi);
```

[image]

And the remaining portion could be had by,

```
animate(plot3d,[sin(Pi*2*x)*sin(Pi*y)*sin(t)
                -sin(Pi*x)*sin(Pi*2*y)*sin(t),
                x=y..1, y=0..1],
        t=0..2*Pi);
```